# File path that modified by concatenating variables not working

Tags: bash, macos, shell, scripting, zsh

I'm trying to make this work. Please help.

```
folder="Test\ Folder"
path="/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/Shared/${folder}"
echo "$path"
if [ -d "$path" ]; then
echo "Yes"; else echo "No"
fi
```

This is the original script I'm working on.

```
echo in point
read inp
echo out point
read op
echo path
read ffolder

fName=`echo "$ffolder" | cut -d'/' -f1`

makejpgs () {
        ffmpeg -y -i "${3}" -ss $1 -to $2 -vf fps=12 "$fName_%d.jpg"
}

path="/Volumes/PROJECTS/Main/${fName}"
files=$(find "$path" -type f -name "*story*")
echo "$files"

for i in $files; do

    echo "$i"
    makejpgs "$inp" "$op" "$i"

done
```

ffmpeg giving error when not using `\` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a value `"between quotes"`, then you do *not* need to `escape\ spaces`. So, change each `\`  into just  .

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked for this script. But next thing is to set that path in to ffmpeg as input path and seems it needs`\ ` That's why I was trying to use them. Sorry for not giving that info. Again thank you Marlon!

Comment: I've added the original script. Could you please take a look? Thank you so much!

Comment: Don’t update your question after it has already been answered. This makes the question go out of sync with answer, which will lead to confusion and will make this entry less useful for others. Instead, revert your update and post it in a new question.

Comment: Ah, Sorry! I didn't know that, it was my first question stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape special characters in your input.

```sh
echo path
read ffolder
ffolder=$(echo $ffolder | sed 's/[`~!@#$%^&*() -_=+{}\|;:",<.>/?'"'"']/\\&/g')
```

On input of `my desktop` it will return `my\ desktop` and similarly for `[my folder]` it will return `\[my\ folder\]`.